# Calling stored procedure in Oracle with complex object type parameters using EclipseLink

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, eclipselink

Due to the [deprecation of JPublisher](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#BABDCAFC) since Oracle 12c we're currently considering other ways how we can call stored procedures with complex object types as parameters instead of generated classes and JDBC.

It seems that [EclipseLink JPA Extensions](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/jpa/extensions/toc.htm) is the only tool that can help with it. Following the examples I found I'd be able to call procedures with simple types as arguments. But I wasn't able to annotate my entity classes so that they would map correctly to the PL/SQL Object types in the database when the objects are a bit more complex.

For example we have a stored procedure that has one input and one output parameter of the same Object type A. The type structure is following:

Object type A contains <- Table type B which is table of <- Object type C which contains <- Table type D which is table of <- Object type E.

I figured I shall use the @OracleObject for the Object types and @PLSQLTable for the Table types but I haven't found a way how to correctly combine them together.

I've tried the following:

```
// All annotations with the required elements

@Embeddable
@Struct
@OracleObject
public class A {
    @Column(name = "B")
    private B b;

    // Getter and setter
}

@Embeddable
@Struct
@PLSQLTable (.., nestedType = "C")
public class B { }

@Embeddable
@Struct
@OracleObject
public class C {}
```

I've tried to add the @PLSQLTable with the proper annotation elements to class A and/or to class C but the Java and DB objects do not map to each other correctly and I'm getting the `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type`during the call.

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could explain to me how to use the annotations to tell the EclipseLink that Object A contains Table B of Object C.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I have been going down the path of Spring Data Oracle Extension project. However the example given is a simple pojo, not a complex object.
Despite a lack of examples anywhere I can find, I was able to pull a very complex object back via SqlReturnSqlData(), but can't seem to find a way to insert a complex object into an oracle stored procedure.  I have yet to find any full example of how anyone  is inserting custom complex Oracle Types. Via Spring or any other way.

Comment: We finally decided to use JDBC. I wrote a simple generator for type classes that implement SQLData interaface as described in [JDBC Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraoot.htm#JJDBC28461). We then use [OracleCallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) together with the generated classes to call the stored procedure.

For the collection type attributes you can use [OracleArray](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraarr.htm#i1056527) within the Java class that implements SQLData.

Comment: Congrats. Were you able to insert with self defined child objects? For example, with a parent Car and child Radio. I have within readSQL method for the parent the following:  setRadio((Radio)stream.readObject() );  Even though it compiles at runtime it throws a casting exception at runtime. xception:oracle.sql.STRUCT cannot be cast to com.foo.beans.Radio  as if it wants radio to be a Struct or STRUCT.  Docs say you don't have to do this, but the docs don't seem to provide a full example of a parent child relationship.  I'm guessing you are doing the same in your readSQL without issue.

Comment: My issue ended up being the typeMap not having values related to the child objects. The  Spring Data JDBC Extensions project does not expose the typeMap easily nor any examples of setting the type map with child objects.